How do I finish the 'Doomsday Animals' quest?
I'm trying to complete the 'Doomsday Animals' quest in Dysmantle's "Pets and Dungeons" DLC.
The quest is prompting me to "Investigate the Secured Retreat at Isle of Doom."

I've fully explored the entire Isle of Doom and the Secured Retreat. I've gotten access to the vault and gotten the Panther recipe -- but the quest still won't progress. (I've actually finished the entire Paws of the Apocalypse quest and fully explored the entire doomsday area.)
Everywhere that I've looked seems to agree that the quest is completed by looting the Vault, and the Panther is the reward. (Eg. the wiki.)
Here I am, in the vault, with my Panther -- and I've still not completed this quest.

How do I complete this quest to get the XP reward?
